# Auto White Balance data

Tags: metadata, white-balance

I am a wedding photographer and work under a wide range of lighting conditions. I prefer to set my white balance with a Sekonic Kelvin meter and use this value in the Kelvin setting on the camera. I also use a wide variety of gels and the Kelvin measurement helps me choose the right gel or combinations of gels to match flash and ambient light. I also find that I need to adjust Tint as an additional setting to get my desired setting. [image]

My question is when using autowhite balance is there any way on recovering the camera calculated values for kelvin and tint?

Answer (score 1):

If you shoot RAW, you can see the values for white balance and tint in Lightroom or the Adobe Camera Raw plugin. If you shoot JPG, you can find the values in Photoshop by going to File --> File Info, then going to Raw Data. If you copy and paste this info into a new Word doc (or other text editor) then do a search for "temperature" and "tint" you should find the values.

[image: screenshot of metadata]